# d3.js set class name using call back function failed

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3.js and tried to set a class using a function but failed.

What I did was draw some rectangles using a dataset like this :

```
[
{id: 0, status: "inital", color: "gray", x: 0, y: 0},
{id: 1, status: "success", color: "green", x: 100, y: 0}
...
]
```

My code works fine except set class which depends on `id`. If `id` is even, it will set to 'first' otherwise it will set to 'second'.

I am even able to console.log, but in the dom, the class is not there. No idea why this happens (perhaps an async issue?). Thank you so much in advance!

```
let rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(stateData, function (d) { 
                        return d.id;
                    })

                rects.enter()
                  .append("rect")
                  .attr("id", function(d) {return "box-" + d.id;})
                  .attr('class', function (d) { 
                          //console.log (setClass(d.id)); it will show 
                          //correctlly
                          setClass(d.id); 
                   })
                  .attr("width", 50)
                  .attr("height", 50)
                  .attr("x", 0)
                  .attr("y", 0)
                  .attr("fill", 'blue')
function setClass (id) {
                if ( id % 2 == 0) {
                    return 'first';
                } else {
                    return 'second';
                }
              }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return setClass(d.id);`? (as you're returning nothing to assign the class)

Comment: thank you let me try, I thought I return it in setClass this function

Comment: cool, fixed it's true I didn't return setClass(d.id) Thank you so much @Shashank

Comment: No sweat. Do you now get it how it worked?

Comment: Yeah, I did totally, thank you so much